# R,S Configuration of asymmetric carbon atom when group priority 3 and 4 are not on wedge bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I am not blessed with the gift of spatial awareness. I understand how to determine the configuration when a group with priority 4 is on the hashed wedge or when the group with priority 4 is on the bold wedge and priority 3 is on the hashed wedge. However are there any rules I can follow for situations as shown in the image? The numbers show the priority.
[image: structures]

Comment: A piece of chewing gum and four matchsticks can be a decent replacement for insufficient spatial awareness. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, Put the lowest priority group as far away from you as possible.

In the 1 example, if I look at 4 from between 1 and 2 it would be farthest away from me. And i will see that the 3 group is on top, 2 on my left and 1 on my right.

And now if i move from highest priority group to lowest (1-2-3) it would be in clockwise sense. So the configuration is R.

2nd and 3rd example has S and R configuration respectively.

Comment: Highest priority to lowest is 1-2-3.